# Proof that $C(K)$ is a Grothendieck space for $K$ an extremely disconnected compact space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

I am looking for a proof, other than the original article by Grothendieck which is in French, that the space $C(K)$ is Grothendieck when $K$ is extremely disconnected.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may want to use the fact that (for extremely disconnected $K$) $C(K)$ is $1$-injective, i.e. there is a norm 1 projection $\ell^\infty(K)\to C(K)$.

Comment: Would you mind considering accepting the answer or asking if anything is unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find one proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128388/ell-infty-a-grothendieck-space?rq=1). Here's a possible different route.

Show that for every compact Hausdorff space $K$, the Banach space $C(K)$ has Pełczyński's property (V):

> A. Pełczyński, Banach spaces in which every unconditionally converging operator is weakly compact, *Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci.* **10** (1962), 641-648.

Show that dual spaces with property (V) are Grothendieck. Conclude that $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ is Grothendieck for any index set $\Gamma$.

Use the fact that $C(K)$ are injective for $K$ extremely disconnected, hence complemented in $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ for some $\Gamma$. Conclude the Grothendieck property.

You may also apply

> T. Andô, Convergent sequences of finitely additive measures, *Pacific J. Math.* **11** (1961), 395-404.

where it is proved that $C(K)$ is Grothendieck for a compact $\sigma$-Stonean space $K$. Extremely disconnected spaces are certainly $\sigma$-Stonean spaces. You may also want to see the proof for compact F-spaces:

> G.L. Seever, Measures on F-spaces, *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **133** (1968), 267-280.