# On the existence of a specific linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Say $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces (of finite or infinite dimension), $T: X \rightarrow Y$ a bounded linear operator and suppose $T$ is injective. Then there exists $S: Y \rightarrow X$, linear and bounded, such that $ST = Id$.

I started off by observing that $T: X \rightarrow T(X)$ is surjective. Then $T: X \rightarrow T(X)$ is bijective and therefore invertible: there exists $S \in L(T(X), X)$ such that $ST = TS = Id$. May I conclude by extending $S$ by $0$ on $Y \setminus T(X)$? Is there another way of proving this result?

Comment: Out of interest, how do you know that $T(X)$ is complete? I don't know how to prove this and am wondering if you could explain it to me.

Comment: I don't know if $T(X)$ being complete intervenes in this proof. I think that one needs $T(X)$ to be closed. The open mapping theorem may yield this result but I am not sure.

Comment: Well $T(X)$ being closed is the same as $T(X)$ being complete, isn't it, because $T(X)$ is a subspace of $Y$ which is complete?

Comment: Don't you need to check that $T(X)$ is closed/complete before you can even begin applying the open mapping theorem to get your $S : T(X) \to X$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, there is an equivalence between the two. And you're right again, one needs $T(X)$ to be Banach in order to use the open mapping theorem. So I don't know how to prove that $T(X)$ is closed, sorry.

Comment: Let $T : l^1 \to l^1 $ map $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (x_2, x_3, x_4 , \dots)$. What $S : l^1 \to l^1 $ satisfies $ST = id$?

Comment: @Kenny Your proposed $T$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. For example, take $T\colon \ell_\infty \to c_0$ given by $T(\xi_k)_{k=1}^\infty = (\xi_k / k)_{k=1}^\infty$. It is injective but it does not have a left-inverse as it is compact.

Even when $T$ is injective and has closed range (which is equivalent to the existence of $\delta>0$ such that $\|Tx\|\geqslant \delta\|x\|$ for all $x$) this need not hold. Indeed, let $T\colon c_0\to \ell_\infty$ be the inclusion map. There is no surjective operator $S\colon \ell_\infty\to c_0$ because $\ell_\infty$ is a [Grothendieck space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128388/ell-infty-a-grothendieck-space).

Comment: Nice!! :) I wish I could favorite also answers in the SE-UI.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your proof will generally not produce a linear operator.  Consider $T:\ell^1\to\ell^1$ given by 
$$Tx(n)=x(n-1).$$
Then we have the left inverse $S:T(\ell^1)\to\ell^1$ defined by
$$Sx(n)=x(n+1).$$
But, we have $y=\left(1,1,\frac{1}{4},\ldots,\frac{1}{(n-1)^2},\ldots\right)\in \ell^1\setminus T(\ell^1),$ and if we extend $S$ to $\tilde{S}$ by means of your proof, we have 
$$\tilde{S}y=0\neq \tilde{S}\left(1,0,0,\ldots\right)+\tilde{S}\left(0,1,\frac{1}{4},\ldots,\frac{1}{(n-1)^2},\ldots\right).$$

Generally, what is required is that $T(X)$ be a [complemented subspace](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementedSubspace.html) of $Y$.  Because then $Y=T(X)\oplus Z$ for some closed subspace $Z$ of $Y$, and we can extend $S$ by linear extension of
\begin{align}
\tilde{S}y=\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
Sy&:&y\in T(X)\\
0&:&y\in Z
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{align}
In this case, we also get preservation of norm, i.e. $\|\tilde{S}\|=\|S\|$.

Comment: An injective operator may be compact hence it cannot have a one-sided inverse.

Comment: @TomekKania If $T$ is compact, the range is either finite-dimensional (in which case $T$ is not injective), or not closed (hence not complemented).

Comment: Sure, I misread your answer.